GitLab agent not selected by default in dynamic environment
We use the Kubernetes GitLab agent in our Gitlab CI to get it deployed in a Kube cluster for dynamic review environments, but the created environment isn't linked to the Gitlab agent, thus leaving the tab “Kubernetes dashboard” empty:

We have to manually edit the environment and select the GitLab agent, for each deployed environment. Is there a way to have it automatically selected? I couldn't find relevant values for this in the environment settings from CI reference.
Relevant code for the job is the following:
deploy:review-app:
  stage: deploy
  interruptible: true
  image: ...
  variables:
    DASHBOARD_URL: https://dashboard-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID.review-apps.mycompany.tech
    HELM_NAMESPACE: gimreviewapp-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS !~ /deploy_review_app_gitlab/
      when: never
  script:
    - helm upgrade --install gim-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID $CI_PROJECT_DIR/review_app/chart --create-namespace --wait --timeout=20m
  environment:
    name: review-app/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: $DASHBOARD_URL
    on_stop: deploy:stop_review
    kubernetes:
      namespace: $HELM_NAMESPACE

We use GitLab Enterprise Edition v17.0.1-ee
